# Multiplying many times

Tags: c++, bitwise

I needed to find away to left shift a number on a platform with buggy `<<` and `>>` bitwise operators. I came up with a rudimentary solution, but it looks ugly and inefficient. What's a better way to do this?

```
float leftShift8(int value) {
    return value * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2;
}

float rightShift8(int value) {
    return value / 2 / 2 / 2 / 2 / 2 / 2 / 2 / 2;
}
```

Comment: buggy shift operators? Are you sure? That sounds very suspect.

Comment: just joking. the actual matter is more complicated so I used that as a justification.

Comment: And on platforms with different endianness, how does this work out (versus your supposed claim of a "buggy" operator)?  You're better off figuring out the actual bug with the shift operators...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't you do something like

```
float rightShift(int value, int numberOfShift)
{
  float result = (float)value;
  while(numberOfShift-- > 0)
     value*=2.0f;
  return value;
}

float leftShift(int value, int numberOfShift)
{
  float result = (float)value;
  while(numberOfShift-- > 0)
     value/=2.0f;
  return value;
}
```

This would especially deal with the fact that you do not return int type, but float. Additionally, its a lot faster to do a 2*2*2 than pow(2,3)

Comment: Multiplying is not faster in C++, the difference in only noticable in C. See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940367/what-is-more-efficient-using-pow-to-square-or-just-multiply-it-with-itself.

Comment: In c++ it doesn't make a noticeable difference. And Jean-François' code is much simpler easier to the programmer to read

Answer (score 7):

If I understand well, you are using a computer that have "broken" bit-wise operators? That is odd but maybe you can try this?

```
float leftShift8(int value)
{
    return pow(2, 8) * value;
}
```

This code simply do a power of 8 on the base that is 2. After that, you multiply by your value. It does the same thing as your code but I'm not sure why anyone would use this instead of bit-wise since bit-wise a much more faster I think.

You could make this more general and useful like this

```
float leftShift(int value, int numberOfShift)
{
    return pow(2, numberOfShift) * value;
}
```

**EDIT: For the edited question about division, the is only a slight change. Thanks to T.C for this (answer below), I include it in my answer to make it more complete**

```
float rightShift(int value, int numberOfShift) 
{ 
    return value/pow(2, numberOfShift); 
}
```

Anyway, I hope it will help.

Comment: Great Jaff, thanks a ton, but can you solve the divide problem as well? Updated question.

Answer (score 3):

Well, going on Jean-François's answer above, to solve the division:

```
float rightShift(int value, int numberOfShift)
{
    return value/pow(2, numberOfShift);
}
```

Again, there you go.